# How to create an iOS IPA file so that someone else can upload it to iOS Appstore?

Tags: ios, air

I'm building an app with someone else. They designed the graphics and I coded it. We're putting it in their app store account which means they did the certificate on their computer.

Since I'm the coder, I've tried building the IPA file on my computer (using the certificate/password from them). It seems to build just fine, but when they try to upload it to iTunes, they get an ITMS-9000 error.

I've built other IPA files and uploaded to my app store account without an issue. So, what am I missing on my side to properly build one with their credentials for their app store account?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Either you give your code to them for packaging or you get all the certificates from them on your computer and then package and upload from your computer. Note: they may have to regenerate certificates again for your computer from itunesconnect.

Comment: OK, I resolved this issue by creating the Certificate Signing Request on my computer and having the account admin use that CSR in his app store account to generate the certificate for the app.